# Android USB Transfer Sizes

Tags: android, usb, data-transfer

I am pretty new to Android, and I currently creating an app that reads data from the USB port. What I want to know is, is there a way to mimic the Windows settings below in Android to change the USB transfer sizes to 64? Currently, I'm receiving Bytes too fast, and I'm losing a large number of packets because of it.

Thanks for any help you can provide!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGIMc.png

Currently using an FTDI FT232R chip. I need to slow down the transfer, because I am trying to display real-time data. Would a better solution be to dynamically use the ByteBuffer?

Comment: If whatever peripheral you are talking to support it, then yes you should be able to adjust this in your USB serial code.  But if at some point there is an actual "serial" wire on the far end, you do have to keep up with that, or the USB serial chip will start dropping data.  So this is probably not the solution you want to pursue.  Can you configure a lower baud rate for both systems?

Comment: @ChrisStratton Smaller transfer sizes would be preferred. The size of the packet is 16 bytes, and I'm receiving ~300Packets/Sec.

Comment: You can't throttle a serial stream by changing the size of the USB packets encapsulating it, at most you can just make it start to fail if the USB can no longer absorb the data the serial line throws at the FT232R.  You really should slow it down by changing the baud rate between the FT232R and whatever it is listening to, or have the remote system send less frequently.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I see, that makes sense! However, this was a solution that was used for the app created on Windows, what would you do then for the Android implementation, if I were not to change the hardware?

Comment: Fix it the right way for android and write a memo pointing out the windows developer's mistake, so that gets fixed too rather than continuing to risk data loss.